# Why does \vspace, after section heading, sometimes jump/snap in discrete steps?

Tags: spacing, debugging

Well, this is one question that I've had for a long time, and one that always gets me extremely irritated. However, this time I'm even somewhat happy - that I can *ask* the question *at all*; and that is thanks to the power of animated .gif `:)`

This is the thing - sometimes there are some designs I'd like to replicate in Latex; usually you read your manuals, you change your lengths, things happen. However, sometimes - and especially after section headings - I'd like to say, lift up or push down the starting paragraph after the section a bit; however, without redefining the master section after skip.

And so I usually insert a `\vspace{\length}` after the section heading, and start tuning `\length`; text starts moving, and then, if I move it for say 1 pt, it almost jumps into that direction; I decrease that to 0.5 pt - the text is as if not moved at all ?! (*and then I start trying `\vspace*`, or `\ \\[\length]`, or whatever works*). And I always want to ask about this - but I can never think of anything better than "*Why does Latex jump vertical space*", and arguably no-one would understand what is going on `:)`. Well, finally, this is what I mean by "jumping" or "snapping" in "discrete steps" ([atest_animate_10_p.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_10_p.gif), 900KB):

[image: atest_animate_10_p.gif]

The MWE for that image is below (compiled with `pdflatex`) - however, it is a `bash` script which generates 100 PDFs, and then extracts images from them, and finally composes the images into an animated gif. Basically, for each "frame" (PDF), the script changes a parameter that ends up as a length, `\mylen`, which is used at only one place: `\ \\[\mylen]`. `\mylen` is increased by a constant step (less than a pt) for each frame; and is written out as the first word in the paragraph.

Notice that instead of a smooth transition, the paragraph "snaps" into place and doesn't move for certain values - and then when it starts moving again, it "jumps" more than usual. And this is actually at some step size of (*Note that you may have some hiccups in your browser while the gif loads; once it is loaded, however, the jumps should be noticeable when the paragraph doesn't move - and the number indication changes nonetheless... although, some frames from the gif may still end up being dropped*)

Well, whenever I come to this problem, I get frustrated of the difficulty to explain it verbally. And then I think, fine - let me cook up an MWE, will be easier for others. Then I write up something minimal, toss `\lipsum[1]` in there - and I cannot demonstrate a problem anymore !! Damn, that always gets me! That is why, the first .gif (and the MWE) is set to `\lipsum[1-10]` - to demonstrate the problem; however, this is what happens if, say, `\lipsum[1-2]` is used instead ([atest_animate_02_p.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_02_p.gif), 899KB):

[image: atest_animate_02_p.gif]

That is - everything goes smooth, as expected (*also built with `pdflatex`*). I discovered more-less by accident, that you cannot demonstrate this "jumpiness" unless you use enough text in paragraphs, so it flows over to the next page!

Finally, I thought, for fun, to generate such an animated gif, but with `lualatex` and `lua-visual-debug` - and this certainly explains something more ([atest_animate_10_l.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_10_l.gif), 1599KB):

[image: atest_animate_10_l.gif]

Namely, here it is noticeable that when the paragraphs "lock" into vertical position - one of those blue lines starts going "up", and then it "jumps down"; what does that mean, however, is beyond me `:)`

So, if anyone can explain what is happenning here - and is there a possibility for "smooth" vertical positioning of overflown paragraphs, please post back...

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Here is the MWE script code ([atextest.sh](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/atextest.sh)):

```
#!/bin/bash

# to force exit loop:
trap 'echo Control-C trap caught; cleanup; exit 1' 2 #traps Ctrl-C (signal 2)

MYFN="atest"
MYFNIMG="${MYFN}_img"
MYFNTEX=${MYFN}.tex
MYFNIN="${MYFN}-input"
MYFNINTEX=${MYFNIN}.tex

function cleanup() {
  echo rm ${MYFNTEX} ${MYFNINTEX} -rf ${MYFN} -rf ${MYFNIMG}
  rm ${MYFNTEX} ${MYFNINTEX}
  rm -rf ${MYFN}
  rm -rf ${MYFNIMG}
}



mkdir ${MYFN}
mkdir ${MYFNIMG}

cat > ${MYFNTEX} <<EOF
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\providecommand{\myparam}{0.0pt}% fallback definition
\tracingonline=0 % suppress stdout (still dumps start)

% tex.se: 47576
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifluatex
  \usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % tlmgr install lua-visual-debug
\fi
\ifxetexorluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
  \setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}
  \newfontfamily\myfontfam[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}
\fi

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%                   % the name
{1}%                         % the level
{\z@}%                       % the indent / 0mm
{-\baselineskip}%            % the before skip / -3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex
{2pt}%          % the after skip / 2.3ex \@plus .2ex
{\centering\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\bfseries}} % the style
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{0pt}
\setlength{\mylen}{\myparam}

\begin{document}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \myfontfam
\fi
  \fontsize{10}{12.3}\selectfont

\title{Testing Title}
\date{October 31, 1000}
\author{John Doe\\\\ Somewhereland}

\maketitle

\clearpage

\input{${MYFNINTEX}}
\clearpage

\end{document}
EOF

cat > ${MYFNINTEX} <<EOF

\section*{Introductory words of introduction}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\vspace{2pt}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Something else here, some other words}
\end{center}

%\vspace{\mylen}
\ \\\\[\mylen]

\makebox[2cm][r]{\the\mylen}, \lipsum[1-10] %[1-2]


\bigskip


\bigskip

EOF

MYPARAM="2.0pt"
JOBNAME="atest1"

#~ CROPPARAMS=320x240+100+400
CROPPARAMS=400x400+150+100

CMDNAME="pdflatex"
#~ CMDNAME="xelatex"
#~ CMDNAME="lualatex"

for ix in $(seq 0 1 100); do
  iy=$(wcalc -EE -q \($ix-50\)/50*30);
  INDEX=$(printf "%03d" $ix) ;
  JOBNAME="${MYFN}${INDEX}" ;
  MYPARAM="${iy}pt"
  echo "
        $CMDNAME - $JOBNAME - $MYPARAM" ;
  (${CMDNAME} -output-directory="${MYFN}" -jobname="${JOBNAME}" "\def\myparam{${MYPARAM}}\tracingonline=0\input{${MYFNTEX}}" 2>&1 1>/dev/null);
  convert -density 150 -crop ${CROPPARAMS} +repage ${MYFN}/${JOBNAME}.pdf[1] ${MYFNIMG}/${JOBNAME}.png ;
done

GRAY=""
#~ GRAY="-type grayscale"
echo convert -delay 5 -loop 0 ${MYFNIMG}/\*.png ${GRAY} ${MYFN}_animate.gif
convert -delay 5 -loop 0 ${MYFNIMG}/*.png ${GRAY} ${MYFN}_animate.gif


# view results
#~ evince ${MYFN}/${JOBNAME}.pdf
#~ display ${MYFNIMG}/${JOBNAME}.png
eog atest_animate.gif 2>/dev/null

cleanup # remove tmp files
```

Comment: Do this jumpiness/snappiness occur regardless of whether `\raggedbottom` or `\flushbottom` are in effect?

Comment: Just wanted to say this is such an excellently and beautifully stated question I'd love to vote up several times if I could :-)

Comment: You should also have recorded the bottom of the page :-)

Comment: I agree with @StephanLehmke.  Very well prepared question!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, all - @Mico and @StephanLehmke, I have just [posted this answer below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56500/2595), with captures of top and bottom, also for `\raggedright` and `\flushbottom`. Cheers!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> So, if anyone can explain what is happenning here - and is there a possibility for "smooth" vertical positioning of overflown paragraphs, please post back...

As Stephan remarked this is a wonderful question to look at, but I think with all the animation and the coding around it you have fairly effectively hidden the problem.

The culprit is the `center` environment just in front of the space that you modify. The problem is that this environment surrounds itself with flexible glue (ie with a stretch and shrink component). The exact values in your case are

```
10pt plus 3pt minus 5pt
```

So in the place where you have your space you really have

```
\mylength + 10pt plus 3pt minus 5pt
```

As it was remarked in other answers TeX attempts to find a page break with minimal badness. So, if we assume that the page break TeX found just naturally fits (ie no shrink or stretch is necessary) then you just get `\mylength + 10pt` at this point. Now if you add 1pt to `\mylength` then the last line wouldn't fit any more on the page, except that your extra point can be absorbed by the shrink on the page.

Now if the only shrink available is in this very place (which it is in your example) then your extra point will just be swallowed and the space remains the same. Same story for adding another pt and another one. (If there are several places with shrink on the page then the shrink gets distributed evening across those places, so in that cases you might see a small increase but less than your step value.)

But the moment you have added 4pt it can't be compensated by the shrink available in your example. Thus the last line now really doesn't fit any more on the page and thus TeX needs to use "stretch" to fill the missing line (minus your 4pt), i.e., 8pt or so depending on the `\baselineskip` setting.

So no more shrink and instead a stretch and your space makes a jump. Adding further pts will increase your space while the need for stretch gets less until you reach the point where the page again is "natural" without a need for stretch and then everything repeats.

Now the `\raggedbottom` setting only effects how the final page is typeset (after breaking it). Basically, the cut-off page is put into a bot of `\textheight` and in case of `\raggedbottom` a `\vfill` is added to the bottom (more or less). Now in the "shrink" situation this doesn't really make a difference as the page is already overfull. And in the stretch situation it means that the stretch in the end is only applied to the bottom and not to the stretchable parts in the middle of the page.

**So in summary:** to avoid your mystery you need to ensure that the space you are trying to adjust has no shrink or stretch component either as part of your adjustment or as part of space visually next to it. Only then you can ensure that the space actually behaves as you expect

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer, @FrankMittelbach! I am aware that all the "zazz" did obstruct the question; but my problem was that I really couldn't formulate it acceptably otherwise! Some of that must have been right, though, because this answer is **exactly** what I needed - a direct relationship between what I see, variable values, and concept of "flexible glue". In  [below post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56500/2595) I've confirmed removing `{center}` works for smooth `\vspace`-ing. Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 16):

LaTeX by default vertically aligns the page content to spread on the whole page, from the top to the bottom, with the exception before manual page break (such as new chapter or usage of `\newpage` or `\clearpage` or at the end of the document.

To achieve this, every vertical space at the page is equipped with some stretch. Even baseline skip has a stretch so the paragraph lines does not need to be at the same distance. In your case, it seems that LaTeX uses the (negative) stretch in the newline `\\` you use to produce the space. Try using `\vspace*{10.0pt}` instead.

It is generally not a good idea to remove stretches from the format-defining lengths, because if you had no vertical stretch on the page at all (i.e. no inter-paragraph nor inter-line nor section spacing stretches), the page will become "short", LaTeX would not be able to fill the whole page and `Warning: Underfull \vbox while \output is active` would appear in the log file. The pages will no have equal height and this makes your document look ugly.

Comment: However, `article` uses `\raggedbottom` by default, which perhaps explains better the "strange" behavior.

Comment: The culprit really is the hidden stretch/shrink coming from a nearby environment, not from \\ and and something like `\vspace*`is not helping here (as it only ensures that the space is not vanishing at a page break).

Comment: Many thanks for that @tohecz - my example was with `\\[]`, however I [changed the example](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atextestb-sh-vss.diff) so it uses `\vspace*` everywhere, image: [atest_animate_l_tb_vss.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb_vss.gif); it still "jumps". @egreg, that sounds correct, I cannot see any difference if I add `\raggedbottom` in [below post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56500/2595). Without `\begin{center}`, as in [@YiannisLazarides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56465/2595)'s post, is smooth. Thanks all - cheers!

Answer (score 11):

The GIF images are great and the bash script kung-fu even greater, however it is instructive to watch both the top as well as the bottom of the page. Here is an image of a slightly different page firstly without any `\vspace` added.

[image]

Note the text starts on line 4 and ends with the word 'donee'.

The next two images set `\vspace*` at `16pt` and `18pt` .

Set `\vspace*{16pt}`

[image]

Set at ``\vspace{18pt}`

[image]

The jumps you experiencing (especially if you use `vspace` rather than the starred version`, is TeX's attempt to always produce a page with a minimum of *badness.*

This is an old problem and in the first published work on typography (1683) by Joseph Moxon, *Mechanick Exercises: Or, the Doctrine of Handy Works Applied to the Art of Printing,* reference is made to adding spaces to balance the text so that the last line always falls at the same place and to even the page.

The best place to start to understand the issues involved is Michael Plass, Ph.D. Thesis, [Optimal Pagination techniques for Automatic Typesetting Systems](https://www.tug.org/docs/plass/plass-thesis.pdf).

The MWE code for the images follows, it will be nice if you could combine it with your GIFs. It is instructive to note and observe TeX's attempt to always end up in a nice page display.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\makeatletter
 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\underline{\the\@tempcnta}}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<48\repeat}}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\scriptsize How to Count Lines}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
%% insert this block within a conditional
 \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\thepage\begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-26,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
      \end{picture}}
 \fancyhead[LO]{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
     \end{picture}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize Draft copy}
%% end conditional
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\rule{10pt}{18pt}Latey
\section*{Introduction}
\vspace*{3pt}
\lipsum[1]

$$f_{nk}=\sum\,{\frac{n!}{
1!^{k_1}\,k_1!\,2!^{k_2}\,k_2!\,3!^{k_3}\,k_3!\,\ldots}}\; 
f_1^{k_1}f_2^{k_2}f_3^{k_3}\ldots\;,$$
summed over all $k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots\geq 0$ 

\lipsum[3]

$$f_{nk}=\sum\,{\frac{n!}{
1!^{k_1}\,k_1!\,2!^{k_2}\,k_2!\,3!^{k_3}\,k_3!\,\ldots}}\; 
f_1^{k_1}f_2^{k_2}f_3^{k_3}\ldots\;,$$
summed over all $k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots\geq 0$ 

\lipsum[5-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @YiannisLazarides - many thanks for your answer! Here is your example scripted: [atest_animate_p_tb_yl.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_p_tb_yl.gif); changes that were done to the script: [atextestb-sh-yl.diff](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atextestb-sh-yl.diff); indeed, `\vspace*` without `\begin{center}` is smoother! Thanks both for the in-depth explanation, and the references (_1683 is awesome `:)`_) - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau The 1683 book is available at google books. Why does the gif shows the text getting beyond the 47th line? It should be moved to next page. Can you also slow the gif a bit? Great idea and good way to convey the question.

Comment: Hi @YiannisLazarides - thanks for the book tip! The gif shows beyond line 47 (apparently) because I've commented your documentclass options `[10pt,twoside]`, and replaced with previous of mine: `[10pt,a4paper]`. Slowing the .gif can probably be done by tuning imagemagick's `convert` options.. I've tried to experiment a couple of times, and such gifs tend to hog my machine; the settings in the OP I've tested and they work reasonably well. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Just realized that for local use - instead of an animated gif - it's probably better to use the [`feh`](http://superuser.com/a/174533/39752) command-line image viewer: point it to the directory of `.png`s (generated by the bash script); and keep (left or right) arrow keyboard keys pressed for animation - or just press them briefly to step through images as frames. For correct ordering of loaded images, call as `feh atest_img/*.png` (not `feh atest_img`). Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Ok, as per [@tohecz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/why-does-vspace-after-section-heading-sometimes-jump-snap-in-discrete-steps/56452#56452)' thread, it wasn't just about use of the starred `\vspace*`; as per [@YiannisLazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/why-does-vspace-after-section-heading-sometimes-jump-snap-in-discrete-steps/56465#56465) thread, avoiding `\begin{center}` helps - which is also explained in [@FrankMittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/why-does-vspace-after-section-heading-sometimes-jump-snap-in-discrete-steps/56470#56470)'s post.

So, in the OP Latex code, the shown page was:

```
\clearpage

\section*{Introductory words of introduction}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\vspace{2pt}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Something else here, some other words}
\end{center}

\ \\\\[\mylen]

\makebox[2cm][r]{\the\mylen}, \lipsum[1-10] 

\bigskip
\bigskip
\clearpage
```

I replaced that with ([atextestb-sh-woc.diff](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atextestb-sh-woc.diff)):

```
\clearpage

\section*{Introductory words of introduction}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\vspace{2pt}
{ % begin group 
\centering\textbf{Something else here, some other words}
} % end group

\vspace{\mylen}

\makebox[2cm][r]{\the\mylen}, \lipsum[1-10] 

\bigskip
\bigskip
\clearpage
```

... And I can confirm that: getting rid of the `center` environment, and replacing it with a `{}` group with `\centering`, will now cause "smooth" vertical space transition due `\vspace` at start of paragraph; shown in [atest_animate_l_tb_woc.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb_woc.gif) (*I think I better stop posting animated gifs inline, four heavy ones are probably enough for this page `:)`*).

Unfortunately, the `\centering` part does not work with this change (the title isn't centered); but at least finally the "culprit" for the vertical space jumpiness is identified and confirmed.

> EDIT: Ok, I can confirm that centering of standalone text is restored, if I wrap the `\centering` stanza in a `\makebox` command, as in:
>
> ```
>  
> { % begin group 
> \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
> \centering\textbf{Something else here, some other words}
> }
> } % end group
> ```
>
> however, <s>the section text is then positioned a little below from where it used to be; and</s> the text paragraph isn't positioned at the same location as previously, in response to the same `\vspace` range (here -30pt to 30 pt). But, the `\vspace` - between section heading and first paragraph - does change smoothly; an animation of this hack is in [atest_animate_l_tb_wocm.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb_wocm.gif). 
>   
>   For easier comparison of animated .gifs, only thing I could find is first create a side-by-side montage of the starter and modified gif using ImageMagick's `convert` (method 2 from "*[Animation Modifications: Side by Side Appending (time synced)](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#append)*"): 
>   `convert atest_animate.gif -repage 1208x402 -coalesce null: \( atest_animate_l_tb_woc.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +604+0 -layers Composite out.gif`  
>   
>  
>   (*note the above command will swap and hog CPU like crazy, but possibly less than the other methods*) and then view: `display out.gif` in ImageMagick's `display`. I couldn't yet find other similar viewer tools that can allow some sort of a step control through animated gif frames (*[feh](https://web.archive.org/web/20140907065222/http://linuxbrit.co.uk:80/software/feh/) doesn't even support animated gifs - just shows the first frame*)
>  
>   Note that the gif will probably start playing with a slow rate of about one frame per second in `display`, haven't found a way to stop it yet - however, [`display`'s keyboard shortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508115059/http://www.urz.uni-heidelberg.de:80/UnixCluster/Hinweise/Hilfe/Anwendung/Grafik/Xpd/ImageMagick/www/display.html#keyb) <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> still work for going to next and previous image in the sequence - so one can somewhat focus on a single gif-frame comparison.

---

In response to @Mico and @StephanLehmke - below is a gif with snippets of both top left (start of paragraph; to left of animation) and bottom left (end of page; to right of animation); the online script [atextest.sh](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/atextest.sh) has been changed correspondingly.

That image is under the same conditions as in the OP - except compiled with `lualatex`, but with the `fontspec` stuff removed ([atest_animate_l_tb.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb.gif)):

HAH - it seems like imgur disabled animated gifs from yesterday to today (*either that, or I haven't enabled one of the JavaScript domains*); so here's the original image from sourceforge:

[image]

I cannot see much differences with `\raggedbottom` ([atest_animate_l_tb_raggedbottom.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb_raggedbottom.gif)) - however, there is an interesting difference with `flushbottom` ([atest_animate_l_tb_flushbottom.gif](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/atest_animate_l_tb_flushbottom.gif)):

[image]

Here there seem to be longer intervals of smoothness - but also bigger jumps ...