# Generating pages in response to iterated parameter on engine level?

Tags: tex-core, debugging

Just to jot this down here, while I have the thought: The method I used for the .gif animations in [Why does \vspace, after section heading, sometimes jump/snap in discrete steps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/why-does-vspace-after-section-heading-sometimes-jump-snap-in-discrete-steps) was basically have a `bash` script call `pdflatex` X ammount of times, each with a new value of a parameter `\mylength`, and generating X output PDF files. Obviously, each time `pdflatex` is called, it has to re-load `\documentclass`, then `\usepackage`s, etc all over again - in one word, time-consuming.

I was thinking - it would be so much better if at a certain point in a .tex document, I could write something like (pseudocode):

```
...
blah blah. 

\newlength{\mylength}
\steplength{\mylength}{2.5pt}{20pt}{0.5pt} % pseudo
\generateParameterSequencePages{}          % pseudo

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{Something here}
\vspace{\mylength}
\textit{Something else here}
\end{minipage}

Blah blah blah....
```

... so when the tex engine encounters `\generateParameterSequencePages`; it basically "saves" the state of the current page; creates a new file, `\jobname_pgY.pdf`, numerated with the current page number (Y in the \jobname document); and inside this new file, it tosses the Z number of iterations (*that `\steplength{\mylength}{startvalue}{endvalue}{step}` would specify*) of `\mylength` in the current page, as separate pages. After its done, the engine exits (*not sure if I'd want the engine going back to tex'ing the original PDF at this point or not*).

So, I'd end up with a new file `\jobname_pgY.pdf`, with Z number of pages, showing the Z iterations of parameter `\mylength` and their effect on layout of pg Y in the original `\jobname.pdf` document. I could imagine this would happen somewhat faster, then having a `bash` script call `pdflatex` each and every time.

Is something like this possible at all with current engine(s)? Would use of `synctex` make a difference here? How about use of `luatex`?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions,
Cheers!

---

EDIT: See also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57507/2595) for a more detailed `lualatex` example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just generate one PDF file using a `\foreach` which is pretty much the technique I used in [Sieve of Eratosthenes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-tikz/44682#44682) to produce the animation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \len in {2.5, 3.0, ..., 20.0}{%
    \newpage%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \textbf{Something here}
    \vspace{\len pt}

    \textit{Something else here}
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @PeterGrill - sorry it took a while, but many thanks for your answer! Here I'm not really interested in generating multiple graphics on a single page - I'm interested in debugging influence of lengths (and other parameters) on the typesetting of a page; I have tried to clarify better in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57507/2595). Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this here, so as not to clog the original question.

But basically, the intent behind the question is to debug influence of lengths on page typesetting... I have now looked a bit into it, and can provide a partial answer: `synctex` "just" establishes correspondence between source .tex and output .pdf for GUI editors - however, `lualatex` was already helpful in understanding things a bit better.

So, I've been looking into [lua-visual-debug.lua](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.lua)/[.sty](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.sty); [LuaTEX Reference Manual (luatexref-t.pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/luatex/base/manual/luatexref-t.pdf); `\AtBeginShipout` from package [atbegshi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) and [the output routine and \box255](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/what-is-box255). Basically, I'd like to handle cases like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \newlength{\mylength}

  \section{Lorem Ipsum}

    \lipsum[1-6]

  \setlength{\mylength}{5pt}
  \vspace*{\mylength}

  \section{Sed commodo}

    \lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

In the example above, I'd like to see the influence of diverse `\mylength`s on the page typesetting. The problem is that we don't exactly know which page is the second section going to end up (ok, I have typeset the file once, so I know it is going to be on page 2 - however, we don't know that a-priori). But in any case, latex would have to typeset at least once up to the `\mylength` part.

Now, as far as I (crudely) understand it, after this `\mylength` part is crossed, the tex engine will keep adding page elements, until the page is overfilled. At this point, we can utilize `\AtBeginShipout` to run a macro or lua script - and apparently some things *can* be changed there; but I'm not yet sure which things or how to change them.

In the example below, I've used lua code (*whose original setup is from [lua-visual-debug.lua](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.lua)*) to basically iterate through all of the nodes in the so-called `AtBeginShipoutBox`. At the moment when `\AtBeginShipout` runs, the `AtBeginShipoutBox` is essentially `\box256`; while `\box255` is `nil`.

This tells me that the output routine has possibly not run yet - and most likely, the pdf page is not generated yet (*and the terminal log indeed shows the script output before the `[1]`,`[2]`... strings that are output upon pdf page generation, I guess*).

So apparently, there should be the possibility to change things - however, I try to insert a `tex.print("\\mylength=20pt ")` as a "hack" in the `\AtBeginShipout` routine - and unfortunately, there is absolutely no change in the generated PDF.

However, *if* there *had* been a change; then I could imagine the following as a solution:

- Place a "marker" in the tex file where we want to examine (*e.g. at the `\setlength` command in the first example in this post*)
- Run latex
- Run `\AtBeginShipout`

  - Has the marker been encountered on this page? If so:
  - Save the page context (style at beginning)
  - set `\mylength` to first step of iteration
  - switch temporarily output to another pdf
  - have output routine run and output a single page
  - From this point on, do *not* return execution priority to latex!
  - Start a loop until last step of iteration
  - Retrieve page context
  - change `\mylength` to next step
  - have output routine run and output a single page
  - (repeat loop)

So, there are two questions here:

- Can we change something like `\mylength` in something like lua code running in an `\AtBeginShipout`; such that latex (re-)typesets the page with the new `\mylength`;
- Is it possible to retrieve something like a "page context" (the "style": fonts, skips etc at the start of the typesetting of a page), save it, and retrieve the saved version, again in something like lua code running in an `\AtBeginShipout`?

As far as "page context", I would consider values of, say `\baselineskip` and such at start of typesetting of a page (this is provided by luatex as `tex.baselineskip`); but also if an environment (such as list) is in effect (I'd have no idea if luatex allows for checking of that or not); presumably, for those variables that luatex provides, it shouldn't be a problem to save their values somehow. But is `tex.baselineskip` in `\AtBeginShipout` the `\baselineskip` at the beginning of typesetting of a given page; or the one at the end (*if, say, you had a `\setlength{\baselineskip}{...}` in the middle of the page*)?

Well, that is as far as I can get now - with my limited understanding of the process, it looks like doing something like this would be possible, though I cannot find an exact procedure. So it would be really good to know if this approach is somehow fundamentally impossible (with current versions of software, at least). Also, possibly related: [Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex).

Anyways, here is the above example, with added lua functions to iterate and print out a node list of a page to terminal:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{everyshi} % use atbegshi instead
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
--~ module(...,package.seeall)
--~ module("...","package.seeall")

  -- running this \AtBeginShipout will typeset "test" (with the quotes) on start of every page other than first (regularly broken paragraph continues)
  function mytest()
    tex.sprint([["test"]]) -- typesets "test" (w/ quotations)
  end

  -- texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/node-ini.lua
  local function simplified(t)
    local r = { }
    for k, v in next, t do
      r[k] = string.gsub(v,"_","")
    end
    return r
  end

  local function table2string(t)
    local ret = ""
    for i,v in ipairs(t) do
      -- print(i,v)
      ret = ret .. "[" .. i .. "]= " .. tostring(v) .. "; "
    end
    return ret
  end

  function print_basic_nodedata()
    local rep = "\n"
    rep = rep .. " ## node.types: " .. table2string(node.types()) .. "\n" -- doesn't list whatsit?!
    rep = rep .. " ## node.whatsits: " .. table2string(node.whatsits()) .. "\n"
    rep = rep .. " ## tex: " .. tostring(tex) .. " / " .. table2string(tex) .. "\n" -- empty at this point
    return rep
  end

  print(print_basic_nodedata()) -- once here, as well

  -- texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/node-ini.lua
  function nodes_fields(n)
    local id = n.id
    --local node_fields   = node.fields
    --local nodecodes     = node.types() -- simplified(node.types())
    --local whatsit_node  = nodecodes.whatsit -- whatsit not listed in node.types(); go explicitly
    --print(id .. " / " .. table2string(nodecodes) ..  " / " .. tostring(whatsit_node))
    local whatsit_node = 8

    if id == whatsit_node then
        return node.fields(id,n.subtype) --node_fields
    else
        local t = node.fields(id)
        return t
    end
  end

  function node_field_vals(n)
    local id = n.id
    local myfields = nodes_fields(n)
    local rep = ""
    local whatsit_node = 8
    local whatsit_node_subtypes = node.whatsits()
    for k, v in next, myfields do
      if ((k>0) and not(v=="head")) then -- k=0 next; k=-1 prev; k=12 head; avoid those
        local vv = ""
        if (v == "subtype") then
          if (n.id == whatsit_node) then
            vv = " (" .. tostring(whatsit_node_subtypes[n.subtype]) .. ")"
          end
        end
        rep = rep .. ".[" .. k .. "/" .. v .. "]= " .. tostring(n[v]) .. vv .. "; "
      end
    end

    if (n.id == whatsit_node) then
      if (n.subtype == 1) then -- 1: "write"
        rep = rep .. table2string(n.data[1])
      end
    end

    return rep .. "\n"
  end

  level = 0

  -- texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lua-visual-debug/lua-visual-debug.lua
  function show_page_elements(parent)
    local head = parent.list
    level = level + 1
    print("") -- just a newline
    while head do
      local spacer = ""
      for i=1,level,1 do
        spacer = spacer .. " "
      end
      print(level .. spacer .. ": " .. tostring(head) .. "/" .. head.id)
      --texio.write("term and log", "\nsomething\n" )
      -- below print is for more verbose information:
--~       print (" " .. spacer .. ": " .. node_field_vals(head) )
      if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then -- hbox / vbox
        show_page_elements(head)
      end
      head = head.next
    end
    level = level - 1
    return true
  end

  function start_inspect_page()
    print("")
    print("Start inspect page")
    print("tex.output: " .. tex.output) -- shows "{\let \par \@@par \ifnum \outputpenalty <-\@M \@specialoutput ..."
    print("tex.box[255]: " .. tostring(tex.box[255])) -- nil here
    print("tex.box[256]: " .. tostring(tex.box[256]))
    print("tex.box[AtBeginShipoutBox]: " .. tostring(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"])) -- same as 256; as it says in log file: "\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box256"
--~     print(print_basic_nodedata()) -- same as the first time
    show_page_elements(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"])
    -- perform hack
    tex.print("\\mylength=20pt ")
    -- tex.tprint({-2,\\mylength=20pt}) -- gets typeset
  end
\end{luacode*}

\AtBeginShipout {%
%\directlua{mytest()}
\directlua{start_inspect_page()}
}
\else
\fi

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
% \directlua{mytest()}

\showboxdepth=100
\showboxbreadth=100
% \showbox255       % > \box255=void here
% \showbox256       % > \box256=void here

\lipsum[1-6]

\setlength{\mylength}{5pt}
\vspace*{\mylength}

\section{Sed commodo}

\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: Just experimented a bit with `tex.set`; it seems some things can be changed in `\AtBeginShipout`, and still have an influence on the produced PDF, such as `voffset`:

```
-- tex.voffset = "-2cm" -- works!
-- tex.set ('global', 'voffset', '2cm') --works!
-- tex.set ('global', '\\voffset', '2cm') -- nowork
tex.set ('voffset', '-2cm') --works!
```

However, `tex.parindent` is listed on the same page in the manual, "4.13.1.2 Dimension parameters", as `tex.voffset` - and yet, the only way a changing effect can be seen on the PDF is with `global`:

```
--tex.set ('parindent', '2cm') -- nowork
tex.set ('global', 'parindent', '2cm') -- work
```

The good with this is that it shows the line-breaking of words different, which I guess "proves" that we can change stuff here - and latex will typeset with changes included. which is good news. Note that `tex.baselineskip` is different:

```
-- tex.set ('baselineskip', '2cm') -- "There should have been a lua <node> here, not an object with type string!:"
-- tex.set ('\baselineskip', '20cm') -- pass, nowork
-- tex.set ('\\baselineskip', '20cm') -- pass, nowork
```

... and the manual also notes: "*4.13.1.4 ... The glue parameters accept and return a userdata object that represents a glue_spec node*"

However, I still cannot find a way to change `\mylength` with `tex.set`, so that is still a part of the problem...

Comment: You should add to the question, rather than writing a non answer: this is a "questions and answers" site.

Comment: Hi @egreg - I was afraid the question would get too long; and when/if the post gets a complete answer, it will sink to the bottom of the page anyways, becoming more of an addendum; so I wasn't thinking its too bad. If it still is, I'll move it upstairs - cheers!